# Android Read Contacts Number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying this

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);

    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int phoneIdx = cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            // Extract the name.
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
            // Extract the phone number.
            String phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
            Log.i("ContentProvider", name);
            Log.i("ContentProvider", phone);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

I am able to read Names but Numbers i am getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get through this tutorial, this could help you out of your problem

Link is provided as below:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html